# Hardlink the contents of a whole directory in windows 7

Tags: python, scripting, batch-file, windows-7-x64, hardlink

Which is the best way to archieve this? I was thinking on a batch script that takes a source folder and a destination folder as inputs, and then iterates recursively over the source folder and for each file creates a hard link to that file (with the same name) in the destination folder.

```
hardlink.bat "src dir" "dst dir"

results:
->src dir\file1 <==> dst dir\file1
->src dir\subdir\file2 <==> dst dir\subdir\file2
```

I tried doing this with a for loop, but my experience with batch scripting is limited, and I don't know how to split the source folder name to recreate the same directory structure in the destination folder. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

P.D: The solution could use any scripting language. I currently have python 2.7.3 installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the free [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) which gives you GUI tools to create hardlinks and is integrated right into Explorer.

If you want to do it from a script, you can execute Windows' [fsutil](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil_hardlink.mspx?mfr=true) utility. Another very good free alternative is the [junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) utility from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals)..

Either can be invoked from a batch script. Likewise, to execute one or the other from a Python script you could use the `os.system()` function or possibly an instance of the `subprocess.Popen()` class.

Comment: Seems nice, I'll take a look at it. However this doesn't answer my question, i would still like to do this from a script (I like to see what happens and would like being able to customize it a bit)

Comment: @PabloMescher: I believe you asked the best way to achieve it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same thing with a Windows batch file, and it really took me a long time... but here it is:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set target=%~f2
if not "%target:~-1%"=="\" set target=%target%\
xcopy /t /e /y "%~f1" "%target%"
cd %1
forfiles /s /c "cmd /v:on /s /c set relpath=@relpath&set relpath=!relpath:~3,-1!&if @isdir==FALSE fsutil hardlink create """%target%!relpath!""" @file>nul&if errorlevel 1 echo Failed for !relpath!"
endlocal
```

It must be run in an elevated command prompt.

**Also, all the paths must not include an `!` character (exclamation mark). Please post a comment if you know how to handle that!**

Comment: @GruffMcGruff Yes, you could. It is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I wish I could simply leave this as a comment to user1537366, but I need 50 reputation to comment :S

To also make the batch file work with exclamation marks, try the following code:

```
@echo off

    set source=
    set target=

    forfiles /s /P "%source%" /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE (mklink /j \"%target%\@relpath\" @path ) else (mklink /h \"%target%\@relpath\" @path )"
```

Comment: To gain reputation, you can answer newest questions.